# Easy way of constructing information message for throwing std::exception using preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, exception, macros, c++14

At certain points of my code I want to throw an exception and give it some information about the code where I've thrown it. Something like

```cpp
void Foo() {
    if(condition)
        throw std::logic_error(ERROR_MSG);
}

// somewhere later in code
try {
    Foo()
} catch (std::exception & e) {
    e.what();
}
```

Now the question is – how do i construct this error message? I would like to give information about the file, the line of code, the function name and a bit of an own information. Something (I suspect) should be pretty standard usage – but after an extensive search I still didn't find something useful about this (as I thought) easy subject.

I just would like to write something like this

```cpp
throw std::logic_arrow("Whoops! Error in (" +
                        __func__ + ") " + __FILE__ + ":" + __LINE__);
```

But this doesn't seem to work for various reasons. Here is what I achieved so far with my search:

- There is already a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597078/file-line-and-function-usage-in-c?rq=1), but this is about *if* one should use these macros, not *how*
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343205/c-concatenating-file-and-line-macros) question deals with concatenating `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in a macro, so I was a bit further to my answer
- The `__func__` macro seems to make difficulties, since "*These identifiers are variables, not preprocessor macros, and may not be used to initialize char arrays or be concatenated with string literals*" following to the [gcc homepage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html). Well, it is now a variable I can use for instance in the `printf` function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295881/c-concatinating-func-and-const-char-literal) – but I didn't manage to master the transfer to my own problem
- One guy was worried about a cleaner solution than Macros, using [inline functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338328/how-can-i-replace-my-c-exception-macro-with-an-inline-function-with-line-a), so I could even improve a solution
- C++14 techniques where suggested in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261915/howto-throw-stdexceptions-with-variable-messages), using `operator ""s`

Comment: If you need a shorthand for throwing exception, you are probably using exception too much.

Comment: I doubt that would be useful. `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` point to where exception is thrown, which is irrelevant for user of your code. What is useful would be file and line where your function is called - but you can't get that information easily. If you need location where exception is thrown, simply use debugger.

Comment: To illustrate, your exception would point to `throw std::logic_arrow(ERROR_MSG);` line, which for users of your function is useless. Better would be to point to `Foo()` line, but that's not trivial.

Comment: Well, of course it would be best to provide information about the whole stack when I throw the exception, but we don't live in a perfect world. What I have now is at least the information where exactly my error happened. BTW I meant std::logic_error, dumb me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this:

```
throw std::logic_error(std::string{} + "Whoops! Error in (" +
                    __func__ + ") " + __FILE__ + ":" + std::to_string(__LINE__));
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00e0928c2ee25536)

Sometimes you can format it like the IDE does its own error messages, then get double-click support.

```
throw std::logic_error(std::string{} + __FILE__ + "(" + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "): [" + __func__ +"] " + "Whoops! Error!  Whodathunk.");
```

or somesuch.

```
template<class E>
[[noreturn]] void fancy_throw( std::string msg,
  char const* file, char const* function,
  std::size_t line
) {
  throw E( std::string{} + file + "(" + std::to_string(line) + "): [" +
    function + "] " + msg );
}
#define EXCEPTION( TYPE, MESSAGE ) \
  fancy_throw<TYPE>( MESSAGE, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__ )
```

and we get:

```
EXCEPTION( std::logic_error, "Whoops! Error!  Whodathunk." );
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/098c57d9e59af204)

I think this is poor.  Instead, we can have a `SOURCE_ERROR` macro:

```
inline std::string make_source_error( std::string msg,
  char const* file, char const* function,
  std::size_t line
) {
  return std::string{} + file + "(" + std::to_string(line) + "): [" +
    function + "] " + msg;
}
#define SOURCE_ERROR(...) make_source_error(__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__ )
```

which places flow control *outside of macros*, but does the string building with the tokens inside the macro, and builds the string inside a normal function.

Only the things that *must* be done in a macro (or copy/pasted everywhere we use it) are done in a macro here.  Which is how it should be.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c1afe377f37ef8f)

`...` and `__VA_ARGS__` are there because the macro language doesn't understand some uses of `,` in C++.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I posted a similar solution four minutes before you, but I didn't use a macro like your `SOURCE_ERROR`. I think I will use that although than I contradict my own comment in @JBL s answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/libs/exception/) which does this and more (it's one of the most lightweight Boost libraries consisting only of a few headers).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does **not** work, at least not in g++ version 6.1.1. It complains about being "`unable to find string literal operator 'operator""__func__'`" and also an "`stray '#' in program`". I tried to insert whitespace as well to remove the '#' but neither did help.

Comment: @claudio sorry for wasting your time, you are right. The issue is that __func__ does not expand to a raw literal but a variable. Also, __LINE__ needs to be stringified with a delayed expansion. I'm removing most of the answer, but I think the Boost.Exception suggestion is still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing that by using a couple of macros (so that it would reduce the hassle of typing the whole thing each time, plus it adds consistency), and then creating temporary `std::string`s to concatenate them easily. There might be a simpler way, but it works well and you only type it once.

```
// Helper macros to convert a macro string constant to an actual string in another macro.
#define STRINGIFY2(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)

#define CURRENT_LOCATION std::string("At "STRINGIFY(__FILE__)":") + __func__ + std::string("(" STRINGIFY(__LINE__) "): ")
```

You can then use it and add some info afterwards that way:

```
throw std::logic_error(CURRENT_LOCATION + "Description here");
```

[Watch it live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4eb60648acec69d9)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is exactly what was written in [second item's link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343205/c-concatenating-file-and-line-macros) and does **not** solve the problem with `__func__`.

Comment: @claudio Sorry, I missed that, but then I don't really get your issue with `__func__`. It's indeed not a macro, but an implicitly declared variable in each function. Edit your question with the actual issue you face with it. In my example, it works, so I don't get the "it does not solve the problem with `__func__`". You might be trying to do something different or facing an issue I don't have. What happened when you "tried to transfer to your own problem"?

Comment: Well, the issue is that I – as explained in the second item – cannot use it to concatenate string literals. I tried (before I knew that) to use it is input for strcat() and strcpy() but both resulted in segfaults. I tried different versions of the macro you suggested resulting in compiler errors. I still think it could work, because in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295881/c-concatinating-func-and-const-char-literal) they used it as input for printf() but I do not know how to define an appropriate function/macro.

Comment: Alright.. And what is the issue with what I do? Basically, in my solution it works because I concatenate an `std::string` with `__func__`, which is a `const char[]`. And `operator+()` is defined for `std::string` and this type in that order. Is it the use of temporary `std::string`? The link you posted show a use of `printf` with `__func__` which is perfectly fine. You can use a `const char[]` as an input for a `printf` format with `%s`. `__func__` is not a string literal, so you should not try to use it as one.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some trying I got an "easy" solution which doesn't even need the use of macros, only an inline function. It does compile with g++ 6.1.1 and also "work" es expected (throwing the exception).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
inline const std::string
Exception_helper(   const std::string msg,
                    const char * const func_name,
                    const char * const file_name,
                    const std::size_t line_number) {
    return msg + " " + func_name + "() in " + file_name + ":" +
        std::to_string(line_number);
}

void Foo() {
    throw std::logic_error(Exception_helper("Whoops! Error in",
                                            __func__,
                                            __FILE__,
                                            __LINE__));
}

int main() {
    try { Foo(); }
    catch (std::exception & e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(1); }
    return 0;
}
```

I could try to even implement Exception_helper as `constexpr` function, but no time for that at the moment.

Again, thanks to all who helped me find an answer. Stackoverflow is the best.

Comment: So you will use a function that forces you to type the same last three parameters each time you call it?

Comment: Yes, I have to, because the last three parameters provide the information about where exactly I've thrown the exception. There is – as far as I know or I can see – no possibility to avoid that (except to use a macro in that place, but that is against my taste or even good style). If I had stored these parameters inside the function body to avoid the last three parameters, the error message would give me every time the place of Exception_helper which is definitely **not** what I want.

Comment: @Yakk used in his solution an macro to avoid the three parameters and I think I will use that

Comment: I do know that (otherwise I wouldn't use a macro, yet alone the `STRINGIFY`) but that's actually exactly the same concept behind what I proposed. So I'm kinda surprised. Have a good day. :)